# NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.vendor_id django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, abstractuser

so i recently changed my project user form to abstract base user and well my users can not add products or view their profile i know its problem in views.py and forms.py but whatever i change it in to is still has some problems beside the error in the title.

views.py

```
rom django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.forms import   UserChangeForm 

from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import  NewUser
from products.models import Product
from .forms import ProductForm
from .forms import UserCreationForm
# Create your views here.
def become_vendor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            vendor = NewUser.objects.create(user_name=user.first_name)

            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()   

    return render(request, 'vendor/become_vendor.html', {'form': form})




@login_required
def vendor_admin(request):
   context = {
       'user':request.user

   }
   vendor = request.user.user_name
   
   return render(request,'vendor/vendor_admin.html',{'vendor': vendor ,'context':context})

@login_required
def add_house(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    
     form = ProductForm (request.POST, request.FILES)

     if form.is_valid():
       product = form.save(commit=False)
       NewUser.user_name = request.user.user_name
       product.slug = slugify(product.عنوان)
       product.save()
       return redirect('vendor_admin')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()  
        return render(request,'vendor/add_house.html',{'form': form})
class UserEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    models = NewUser
    form_class = UserChangeForm
    template_name = 'vendor/edit_profile.html'
    seccess_url = reverse_lazy('vendor_admin')
    def get_object(self):
     return self.request.user
```

forms.py

```
rom django.forms import ModelForm
from products.models import Product
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import NewUser


class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields =['نوع_قرارداد','عنوان','تصاویر','قیمت','توضیحات']
       



class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ( 'user_name', 'email','phone','password')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='رمزعبور', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='تایید رمزعبور', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('user_name', 'email' ,'phone',  'profile_pic',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("گذرواژه ها مطابقت ندارند")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ( 'user_name','email','phone', 'about', 'profile_pic',)

    def clean_password(self):
        
        return self.initial["password"]
```

i dont know if the models might be the problem or not but i add them anyways

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('لطفا یک ادرس ایمیل بدهید'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name,
                          first_name=first_name, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

def get_profile_image_filepath(self,filename):
                    return f'uploads/{self.pk}/{"profile.png"}' 
def get_default_profile_image():
                    return "uploads/profiled.png"           


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.CharField(_('ایمیل'),max_length=255 ,unique=True)
    user_name= models.CharField(_('نام کاربری'),max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('نام مسکن'),max_length=255 , blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('شماره همراه'),max_length=50, blank=True)
    تاریخ_ثبت_نام = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='تاریخ_ثبت_نام', auto_now_add=True)
    اخرین_ورود = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='اخرین_ورود', auto_now=True)
    about = models.TextField(_(
        'درباره شما'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(_('عکس پروفایل'),max_length=255 ,upload_to=get_profile_image_filepath,null=True ,blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name    
    def get_profile_image_filenames(self):
                    return str(self.profile_pic)[str(self.profile_pic).index(f'uploads/{self.pk})/'):]
```

please consider the fact that iam new in django i really appericate any help for my project
and if  anyother mistake has been made please inform me i really appericate it.

and here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.vendor_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "X:\website\vendor\views.py", line 59, in add_house
    product.save()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 743, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 885, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1301, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1441, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 416, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /add_house/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.vendor_id
```

product app models.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files import File
from django.db import models
from vendor.models import NewUser


# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    ordering = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering =['ordering']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
class Product(models.Model):
    نوع_قرارداد= models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, related_name='products',null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    عنوان = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    توضیحات = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    قیمت = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10 , decimal_places=4)
    date_added =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    تصاویر = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',)

    class Meta:
        ordering =['-date_added']
    def __str__(self):
         return self.title
    def get_thumbnail(self):
        if self.thumbnail:
            return self.thumbnail.url
        else:
            if self.تصاویر:
                self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.تصاویر) 
                self.save   
                return self.thumbnail.url
            else:
                return 'http://placehold.jp/240x180.png'      
    def make_thumbnail(self,تصاویر, size=(300 , 200)) :
         img =Image.open(تصاویر)
         img.convert('RGB')
         img.thumbnail(size)

         thumb_io = BytesIO()
         img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG',quality=90)
         thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=تصاویر.name)
            
         return thumbnail
```

Comment: Edit your question with the stack trace of the error. Remember to switch the stack trace to copy and paste view.

Comment: you have an error in your view where you call ```product.save()``` in the ```add_product``` method. I figure you have a ```vendor``` as a foreignkey to ```product``` in your ```models.py``` and you're trying to save a product without adding a vendor to it. You can either add ```null=True``` in the vendor field of the product model or add a vendor when creating new product. To give you a better answer I'd have to see ```ProductForm```. Also encapsulate your traceback in backticks

Comment: thansk alot for help i got it my `ProductForm` is in the `forms.py` section and its just title,picture,kind,price,description but if it helps i added my product app `models.py` i also added `null=True` in the `models.py` but still gettting the same error do you think anything else needs a change? thanks alot again

Comment: add ```vendor``` to your ```ProductForm``` fields.

Comment: thanks alot my friend but now i get this error `ValueError: The view vendor.views.add_house didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: I'm just seeing this. Your ```add_house``` view is not properly indented. Your ```form.is_valid()``` block should be under your ```request.POST``` block